# How to create custom text to display questions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm displaying questions in my view like this:

```
<% @categories.each do |category| %>
    <h1><%= category.name %></h1>
    <% category.questions.each do |question| %>
         <ul>
             <li><%= link_to question.id, question_path %></li>
         </ul>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I'm linking to the question's id but ids are different, like 4, 6, 25, 30.

But I need questions to start from 1 like this:

```
Category1   
1 2 3 4 5 6 7


Category2   
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

How do I create custom text for displaying questions like above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `each_with_index` to get the index of the question (with respect to the category):

```
<% category.questions.each_with_index do |question, i| %>
     <ul>
         <li><%= link_to (i + 1), question_path %></li>
     </ul>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I only added i + 1 so that counter starts from 1not from zero.         `<li><%= link_to i + 1, question_path %></li>`
But I'll accept your answer

Comment: You can also use `each.with_index(1)` to handle the offset